# Program not determining if the string is a palindrome

Tags: java, input, palindrome

having a slight issue with my program for class. the program should determine if the string the user inputs is a palindrome or not, the program itself can determine if a simple string like, "aba" is a palindrome but when the user inputs something such as, "one, two, three, two, one" it automatically declares it as not a palindrome. This program is in java, just wondering what i could change to allow the program to be able to read strings such as the second one.

```
import java.util.*;

class Palindrome
{
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
       String original, reverse="";
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
  original = in.nextLine();

  int length = original.length();

  for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
     reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

  if (original.equals(reverse))
     System.out.println("Yo! That is a palindrome.");
  else
     System.out.println("No! That is not a palindrome.");

    }
  }
```

This is the code i'm working with at the moment.

Comment: The string "one, two, three, two, one" is *not* a palindrome. It starts with "o" end ends with "e"... nothing in your code is word-based (and neither are palindromes, normally) - it's all *character*-based. It sounds like you want "word-unit palindromes" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Character.2C_word.2C_or_line_unit

Comment: An example of a palindrome is: "racecar"

Comment: 'madam' is a palindrome

Comment: Are you considering words to check for palindrome?

Comment: Ohhhhh look at that; Meant to ask on the program to determine a palin-LIST. Was clear on the whole palindrome aspect, program needs to determine is STRING is a palindrome, my bad. Sorry. @Braj

Answer (score 0):

The string which you tried is not a palindrome.. palindrome is something like madam where when you reverse all letters the word remains unchanged

Comment: And this is the short version of the most upvoted comment. It should be no more than a comment.